# How can we check if an input string is a valid double?

Tags: c

If I'm reading numbers of type **double** from stdin, how can I check if the numbers being read are in fact valid (that the numbers are in fact a double)?

Comment: How do you define "not double"?

Comment: As opposed to...letters?

Comment: Jim, how about the letter "e"?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`strtod`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtod). Check if the result is zero and subsequently if `endptr == nptr`, according to the man page:

> If no conversion is performed, zero is returned and the value of nptr is stored in the location referenced by endptr.

Something like this:

```
char input[50];
char * end;
double result = 0;

fgets(input, sizeof input, stdin);

errno = 0;

result = strtod(input, &end);

if(result == 0 && (errno != 0 || end == input)){
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: input is not a valid double\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

**EDIT** there seems to be a bit of a discrepancy between [the standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/functions/strtod.html) and the man page. The man page says that `endptr == nptr` when no conversion is performed, while the standard seems to imply this isn't necessarily the case. Worse still it says that in case of no conversion `errno` **may** be set to `EINVAL`. Edited the example code to check `errno` as well.

Alternatively, `sscanf` could be used (preferred over `scanf`), in conjunction with `fgets`:

```
/* just fgetsed input */
if(sscanf(input, "%lf", &result) != 1){
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: input is not a valid double\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Also, don't forget to check the return value of `fgets` for `NULL`, in case it failed!

Comment: "while the standard seems to imply this isn't necessarily the case." -->  C11 §7.22.1.3 7 : "If the subject sequence is empty or does not have the expected form, no conversion is performed; the value of nptr is stored in the object pointed to by endptr, provided that endptr is not a null pointer."  `endptr == nptr` is a sufficient test for no conversion.

Answer (score 2):

Neither simple `strtod` nor `sscanf` are enough to distinguish cases such as `1,5` or `1blah` from desired `1.0` - All of these will result in `1.0`. The reason is that

> The `strtod()`, `strtof()`, and `strtold()` functions convert the **initial** portion of the string pointed to by nptr to double, float, and long double representation, respectively.

To ensure that the *entire* string was a valid double literal, use `strtod` like this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>

...

char *endptr;
errno = 0;
double result = strtod(input, &endptr);
if (errno != 0 || *endptr != '\0') {
    fprintf(stderr, "the value could not be represented as a double exactly\n");
}
```

The `errno` will be set if the value cannot be represented (`ERANGE`). Additionally, `end` will be pointing to the first character not converted. If the locale **has not been set**, when parsing `1,5` or `1blah`, `endptr` will point to the *second* character. **Iff** the entire string was successfully parsed as a double constant, `*endptr` will point to the terminating *'\0'*.

Note that the `errno` must be set to zero prior to calling the function, otherwise it will retain the value from a previous failed function call.

Comment: When `input[0] == 0`, `errno != 0 || *endptr != '\0'` is still false as `errno` may remain 0.   Also suggest `fprintf(stderr, ...`

Answer (score 0):

> How can we check if an input string is a valid double?

Start with
`strtod()` for `double`,
`strtof()` for `float` and
`strtold()` for `long double`.

```
double strtod(const char * restrict nptr, char ** restrict endptr);
```

> The `strtod`, ... functions convert the initial portion of the string pointed to by `nptr` to `double` ....
>
> A pointer to the final string is stored in the object pointed to by `endptr`, provided that `endptr` is not a null pointer.
>
> C11dr §7.22.1.3 2&5

Simplified code to check loosely for validity.  Does not complain about over/underflow nor extra text.

```
// Return true on valid
bool valid_string_to_double(const char *s) {
  char *end;
  strtod(s, &end);
  return s != end;
}
```

---

Challenges of using `strto*()` include: `errno == RANGE` on arithmetic overflow and *maybe* [underflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_underflow).   The return value on overflow is only specified in default rounding mode. That value is `HUGE_VAL` which may be an infinity or a great number.  The return value on underflow is implementation defined.  `errno` has been known to be set to other non-zero values on conditions not specified by the C spec.  Leading white-space is allowed, trailing white-space is not considered.

---

Sample function that looks for 1) conversion, 2) extra space, 3) over/underflow.  It not only returns a valid indication, it also addresses the value of the conversion and the state of `errno` afterward.

```
// Return 0 on success
// Return non-0 on error, adjust these values as needed - maybe as an `enum`?
int convert_string_to_double(double *y, const char *s) {
  char *end;
  errno = 0;
  *y = strtod(s, &end);

  if (s == end) {
    return 1; // Failed: No conversion, *y will be 0
  }

  // This may/may not constitute an error - adjust per coding goals
  // Too great or too small (yet not exactly 0.0)
  if (errno == ERANGE) {
    if (fabs(*y) > 1.0) {
      return 2; // Overflow
    }

    // In the case of too small, errno _may_ be set. See §7.22.1.3 10.
    // For high consistency, return 0.0 and/or clear errno and/or return success.
    // *y = 0.0; errno = 0; 
  }

  // What to do if the remainder of the string is not \0?
  // Since leading whitespace is allowed, 
  // let code be generous and tolerate trailing whitespace too.
  while (isspace((unsigned char) *end)) {
    end++;
  }
  if (*end) {
    return 3; // Failed: Extra non-white-space junk at the end.
  }

  return 0;  // success
}
```

---

> If the result underflows (7.12.1), the functions return a value whose magnitude is no greater than the smallest normalized positive number in the return type; whether `errno` acquires the value `ERANGE` is implementation-defined.  C11dr §7.22.1.3 10

---

A consideration includes the value of `errno` after this function is done.  The C spec only species `errno == ERANGE` for `strtod()`, yet various implementations have been known to set `errno` to other values for other reasons including "no conversion". Code could clear `errno` except when `ERANGE` for high consistency.

Answer (score -1):

You could use the standard atof function. It returns 0 on fail - and you could test if the string was 0 beforehand.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atof/

Comment: the strtod() function gives more information about conversion errors.

Comment: Looks similar to me: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtod/   Is endptr guaranteed not to change if it isn't a double?