# check if input is 3.5 instead of 3,4 for float numbers in C

Tags: c, argc

I have to write an Insertion-Sort programme where i have to check all possible error-handlings.

But how can I check when the user tips in the arguments 3,4 instead of 3.5?

for example: ./sorter 1,4 1,3 1,5 
instead of : ./sorter 1.4 1.3 1.5

Thank you in advance!

Comment: so how do you now handle them? Where's the [mcve]? Or is this just some hypothetical code?

Comment: this is just hypothetical ... just for instance for the input from the user.
the other error-handlings like min. number of argc arguments etc. are working fine, i just don't know how to check if , instead of . is used

Comment: @alk the duplicate actually doesn't answer this :D

Comment: fixed: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46756529/918959