# Trying to convert type char to type float, but gettng segmentation fault

Tags: c, pointers, struct, segmentation-fault, type-conversion

I am attempting to complete an exercise that should help to solidify my knowledge of pointers and structs, where a struct pointer is passed to a function as a parameter. The provided solution uses `scanf` to obtain user input and works very well, but as this function (method?) is considered unsafe, I am attempting to find an alternative way of achieving the same result.

The issue is that one struct member, being of type float, is causing a segmentation fault, where I am converting user input from `char` to `float` by using `strtof()` in conjunction with `fgets()`. I have previously looked at a few string functions that I thought might be helpful (`atof()` and `atoi()` - casting this function's return value to float), but have been unable to successfully implement the conversion with those. As I mentioned, I am attempting to use `strtof()`, but again, I have not been successful.

Here is an example of the problem:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

struct Stock {
    float cost;
};

#define SIZE 50

void ReadIn(struct Stock *purchase);
void PrintOut(struct Stock *receipt);

int main ()
{
    // instantiate struct type
    struct Stock product;
    // instantiate struct type pointer
    struct Stock *pItem;

    pItem = &product;

    if (pItem == NULL)
    {
        exit(-1);
    }
    else
    {
        ReadIn(pItem);

        PrintOut(pItem);
    }

    return 0;
}

//---- Function Definitions ----//

// read function
void ReadIn(struct Stock *purchase)
{
    char pNum[] = {0};
    char *pEnd;

    printf("\nEnter the price: ");
    fgets(pNum, SIZE, stdin);

    pEnd = (char *) malloc(SIZE * sizeof(char));

    purchase->cost = strtof(pNum, &pEnd);
}

// print function
void PrintOut(struct Stock *receipt)
{
    printf("\nPrice: %.2f\n", receipt->cost);
}
```

I know there are mistakes in my implementation, but I don't know how to resolve them. I have used various debugging techniques (printf, IDE built-in debugger, lldb), but I find the results difficult, if not impossible, to interpret. I would appreciate some help.

Comment: You don't need to malloc memory for `pEnd`. See how it's used [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19671001/how-can-we-check-if-an-input-string-is-a-valid-double)

Comment: Use the tags to communicate the language.

Comment: Den, sometime a floating point value as text is much more than `SIZE 50` characters. How about 500?

Comment: @Barmar thank you for the examples, which also reference documentation. I'll need to pore over it for some time to be better familiar with `strtof()`. My use of `malloc` was a desperate attempt at finding a solution to the problem of invalid memory access (and poor understanding of the tools I'm trying to use).

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica thank you for your observation. I hadn't considered the size of a floating point value as text being particularly large; I was just making sure the implementation worked and then, only to the extent of "supermarket prices". Now, I'll have to investigate this a little further. Thank you for pointing out.

Comment: @tadman I'm not sure what you mean by "Use the tags to communicate the language"; could you explain?

Comment: @Den He means you don't need to put **[c]** in the question title, since it's already in the tags.

Comment: @Barmar: thank you for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
char pNum[] = {0};
```

defines `pNum` as an array with a *single* element. It can only an empty string (containing only the null-terminator). Attempting to store more than that single element will go out of bounds and lead to *undefined behavior*

If you want to store up to `SIZE - 1` characters in that array you need to make it `SIZE` big:

```
char pNum[SIZE];  // Initialization is not needed, will be filled in by fgets
```

---

You also misunderstand how [`strtof`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtof) is working. You should not allocate memory for the pointer passed as the second argument. What's happening is that it's a way to emulate *pass by reference* by passing a pointer to a variable.

And anyway, it's okay to pass a null pointer:

```
purchase->cost = strtof(pNum, NULL);
```

Comment: Thank you for your observations. I changed `pNum` as suggested and it seems to have resolved the problem. As to 'strtof'; I was looking at all sorts of permutations to get the program to work, realising that 'strtof(pNum, &pEnd)' is incorrect (in this instance, as I have seen an example of that implementation elsewhere); I had implemented the function per your example (and without malloc), but with other aspects of my code not being correct, I could not be certain that my implementation of 'strtof' was correct.

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem:

```
char pNum[] = {0};
```

You've declared `pNum` to store exactly one (1) character - it cannot store `SIZE` characters.  Any time you try to read into it you will have a buffer overflow.  You need to declare it as

```
char pNum[SIZE+1] = {0};  // +1 for the string terminator
```

Secondly, you shouldn't allocate any memory to `pEnd` - `strtof` will simply set it to point to the first character in `pNum` that is *not* converted to a `float`.   You should check `pEnd` to make sure it's a whitespace character - that way you know the user entered a valid floating-point string.

Here's an example of how to do validation:

```
void ReadIn(struct Stock *purchase)
{
    char pNum[SIZE+1] = {0};
    int done = 0;
    float tmp;

    do
    {
      printf("\nEnter the price: ");
      if ( fgets(pNum, sizeof pNum, stdin) )
      {
        /**
         * Do not update your target variable until after you've
         * validated the input.  pEnd will point to the first
         * character in pNum that is *not* part of a valid floating
         * point string.  
         */
        tmp = strtof( pNum, &pEnd );

        /**
         * isspace returns true/false - we'll assign the result to done
         * to control our do/while loop.  Basically, as long as the user
         * does not enter a valid floating-point value, we'll continue the
         * loop.
         */
        if ( !(done = isspace( *pEnd )) )
        {
          /**
           * If pEnd doesn't point to a whitespace character, then 
           * the input is invalid.  Write an error message
           * and get them to try again.  
           */
          fprintf( stderr, "%s is not a valid input - try again!\n", pNum );

          /**
           * If there's no newline in pNum, then the user entered
           * a string that was too long for the buffer - read any
           * remaining characters from the input stream until we see
           * a newline.
           */
          if ( !strchr( pNum, '\n' ) )
            while ( getchar() != '\n' )
              ; // empty loop          
        }
      } 
      else
      { 
        /**
         * There was a read error on the input stream - while there may be
         * ways to recover, for the sake of this example we'll treat it
         * as a fatal error and exit the program completely.
         */
        fprintf( stderr, "Input error while reading stdin - bailing out...\n" );
        exit(0);
      }
    } while ( !done );

    /** 
     * NOW we've made sure our input is valid, so we can assign it to the
     * target variable.
     */
    purchase->cost = tmp;
}
```

Comment: "If pEnd doesn't point to a whitespace character, then the input is invalid.".  Usually, yet valid input string could have ended with a _null character_ when the input closed or the buffer was just filled.  OTOH `"123 xsd"` would pass this code.

Comment: @JohnBode: thank you for the validation implementation. I was considering how I might go about validating input, but as I have not gotten to the point of error-checking in my course, I might be jumping-the-gun, although, it's good that I got a sneak peek at how I such validation could be gone about. An aside: you guys are really fast with your replies!

Comment: @JohnBode: I've incorporated your code and it works well, except where I press carriage-return, not having entered a number; the program runs to the end and exits. Checking that a correct input has been made after pressing carriage-return is something I have been investigating, but cannot seem to get past `isspace` in order to introduce `\r`. Further, deeper research necessary.